# Display confirmation message before delete operation in Datagrid for Command Field

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a datagrid with  CommandField to Delete a row . How to ask the user for confirm Delete before delete the row .

```
<asp:CommandField HeaderText="Изтрий" ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="Изтрий" />
```

Comment: Add a event for the button and handle inside it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" ImageUrl="/Images/icons/user_delete.png" 
 ToolTip="Delete Product" CommandName="Delete"   OnClientClick="return confirm('Do you want to delete this product size ?')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This example wiil help you.If you are using asp control use `OnClientClick="logout()"` whatever is your function

```
<script>
function logout()
{
if (confirm('Are you sure you want to logout?'))
location.href = "http://www.tackleprices.com/merchant/logout.php";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**add confirm message for Delete Button in data grid using Jquery**

you can set a class for your delete button like this.my class is "btndelete"

```
 <asp:ButtonColumn ItemStyle-CssClass="btndelete"  ButtonType="PushButton" CommandName="Delete" Text="delete"></asp:ButtonColumn>
```

**then write Jquery code**

```
  $('.btndelete').live('click', function () {
            return confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?");
        });
```

this work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code-project article which exactly describe what you want to archive:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32756/ASP-NET-GridView-delete-confirmation-using-asp-Com

HTH